# Forcing all implementations of a trait to override equals

Tags: scala

I have a trait for which I know that reference equality is never the correct implementation of `equals`. Implementations of the trait can be written by many users, and practice shows that sometimes they fail to override `equals`. Is there a way to require it?

In practice implementations are usually case classes, which override `equals` automatically, and we can approach requiring *that* by having `Product` as the self-type of the trait, however, I'd like to see a solution which allows non-case classes overriding `equals` as well (EDIT: Using `scala.Equals` as the self-type is a closer approximation to what I want, since it's still implemented automatically by case classes, but can be usefully implemented by non-case classes and isn't a large burden on people writing implementations).

One more approach I thought of while writing this question is to override `equals` in the trait to call an abstract method, but unfortunately, this doesn't work for case class implementations.

Comment: What about - trait Foo{
    override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = ???
  }

Comment: Could you describe more about _doesn't work for case class implementations_  ? [This worksheet](https://gist.github.com/Odomontois/865d91180cc2e30435bf) worked nice for me

Comment: @Maxim The problem is that when `equals` is redefined in an ancestor of a case class, implementation isn't generated.

Comment: @Odomontois I want case classes to just work since they redefine `equals` already, without having to define something like `isEqual`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use typeclass contract instead of pure trait? [We have one already](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.1/scalaz_2.11-7.1.1-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.Equal) in [`scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), and it's easy to glue it with `Equals` trait:

```
import scalaz._

case class X(a:Int,b:Int)

class Y(a:Int,b:Int)

implicit def provideDefaultEqual[T <: Equals]:Equal[T] = new Equal[T] {
  def equal(a1: T, a2: T) = a1 == a2
}

implicitly[Equal[X]]

implicitly[Equal[Y]] //compile error
```

If you need to wire this with your trait, [there is your own nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6984823/210905)