# Spark/scala create empty dataset using generics in a trait

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-reflect

I have a trait called that takes a type parameter, and one of its methods needs to be able to create an empty typed dataset.

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
    val sparkSession: SparkSession
    val spark = sparkSession.session
    val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext

    def createEmptyDataset(): Dataset[T] = {
        import spark.implicits._ // to access .toDS() function
        // DOESN'T WORK.
        val emptyRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq[T]())
        val accumulator = emptyRDD.toDS()
        ...
    }
}
```

So far I have not gotten it to work. It complains `no ClassTag for T`, and that `value toDS is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to provide both `ClassTag[T]` and `Encoder[T]` in the same scope. For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, Dataset, Encoder}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag


trait MyTrait[T] {
    val ct: ClassTag[T]
    val enc: Encoder[T]

    val sparkSession: SparkSession
    val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext

    def createEmptyDataset(): Dataset[T] = {
        val emptyRDD = sparkContext.emptyRDD[T](ct)
        spark.createDataset(emptyRDD)(enc)
    }
}
```

with concrete implementation:

```
class Foo extends MyTrait[Int] {
   val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
   import sparkSession.implicits._

   val ct = implicitly[ClassTag[Int]]
   val enc = implicitly[Encoder[Int]]
}
```

It is possible to skip `RDD`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, Dataset, Encoder}

trait MyTrait[T] {
    val enc: Encoder[T]

    val sparkSession: SparkSession
    val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext

    def createEmptyDataset(): Dataset[T] = {
        spark.emptyDataset[T](enc)
    }
}
```

Check [How to declare traits as taking implicit "constructor parameters"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6983759/8371915), specifically [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990749/8371915) by [Blaisorblade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53974/blaisorblade) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6984823/8371915) by [Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov).